# How can I redirect to a separate view based on user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So here's what I'd like to do. I have a page at /Admin/Vendors/Index. If a user is in a certain role and they go to this page, I want them to be redirected to another view that only shows them certain data.

Here's what I have:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (User.IsInRole("Special User"))
    {
        SpecialIndex();
    }

    return View();
}


public ActionResult SpecialIndex()
{
    var viewModel = GetSpecialData();

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

So I thought that if the user was in the role and it calls the `SpecialIndex` method, it would call the method and send the user to the `SpecialIndex` view.

It does call the `SpecialIndex` method, but when I call `return View(viewModel)`, it just goes back to the `Index` method, and the user is shown the `Index` view instead of `SpecialIndex`.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Change it to `return SpecialIndex();`

Comment: Or move the `return View(viewModel)` in your `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `View()` constructor that gets a view name in which case you can specifically say which view you want to return, or use the `RedirectToAction` method to redirect to the `SpecialIndex` action. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (User.IsInRole("Special User"))
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction("SpecialIndex");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `User.IsInRole("Special User")` it will solve your problem. Either way, you are returning a view for it.